# Calling an object of a method of a class within another method of the same class

Tags: python, class, object, methods

I was trying to call the objects of a method in one of my classes within antoher method of the same class. Below you can find a small example of how I tried to do it:

```
class example_class():
    
    def some_method(self):
        #... calculate something ...
        a = 1 
        b = 2

    def second_method(self):
        call = self.some_method()
        c = call.a + call.b
```

If I do this, I get the error: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'".
I am sure this is a fearly basic problem, but I am using classes, objects and methods for the first time and would really appreciate the help!

Thank you in advance and stay safe!

Comment: Your variable `call` is equal to `None` because `some_method` does not return any value.
Also `a` and `b` are local variables of `some_method` and cannot be accessed from outside.

Comment: Methods are basically just functions used in the context of an instance. There is no such thing as "objects of a method" - a and b are regular function locals and gone after the function is done. You should return whatever you want to use outside of the function.

Comment: MisterMiyagi, I learned that Variables that are  defined within an Method of class are called 'objects'... thats why referred to the variables as objects. Maybe I got something wrong here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class example_class():

    def some_method(self):
        #... calculate something ...
        self.a = 1 
        self.b = 2

    def second_method(self):
        # call = self.some_method()
        c = self.a + self.b
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```py
class example_class:
    def some_method(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
    def second_method(self):
        self.some_method()
        print(self.a + self.b)
```

You can't access a method's local variables from another method, you should store them as attributes.